# Cakephp - last message

Tags: cakephp

//message belongs to user

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'FromId'=>array(
        'className'=>'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'sender_id'
    ),
    'ToId'=>array(
        'className'=>'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'recipient_id'
    )); //end belongsto
```

the sender_id number 1 sent "Hi" to recipient_id 2 on 2015-03-08 at 10:30:10

the sender_id number 1 sent "Hello" to recipient_id 2 on 2015-03-08 at 11:00:20

My purpose is to select the last message (hello) and the max date of created (2015-03-08 11:00:20)

This is my query

```
    $idAuth = $this->Auth->user('id');
$conversationInProgress = $this->Message->find('first', array(
        'fields'=> array(
                'ToId.id','Message.content', 'Message.conversation_id', 'MAX(Message.created) AS created'),
        'conditions' => array( 
                    'OR' => array(
                        array('Message.sender_id' => $idAuth),
                        array('Message.recipient_id' => $idAuth))),
        'group' => 'Message.conversation_id',
        'order' => array('Message.created DESC')));
```

Below my result :

```
array(
'ToId' => array(
    'id' => '2'
),
'Message' => array(
    'content' => 'hi',
    'conversation_id' => '0fb6dcd8e1'
),
(int) 0 => array(
    'created' => '2015-03-08 11:00:20'
))
```

The expected result:
the content linked to max created (2015-03-08 11:00:20) is "Hello" not "Hi".

Could you please help me.

Thanks

---

It works with subquery, but I am facing an other issue

below my code

```
$conditionsSubQuery = array(
            'OR' => array(
                        array('sender_id' => $idAuth),
                        array('recipient_id' => $idAuth)));

        $db = $this->Message->getDataSource();
        $subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
            array(
                'fields'     => array('MAX(id)'),
                'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this->Message),
                'alias'      => 'SubTable',
                'limit'      => null,
                'offset'     => null,
                'joins'      => array(),
                'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
                'order'      => 'id DESC',
                'group'      => 'conversation_id'
            ),
            $this->Message
        );

        $subQuery = ' Message.id IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';

        $subQueryExpression = $db->expression($subQuery);
        $conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;
        $conversationInProgress = $this->Message->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```

$this->set(compact('conversationInProgress'));

this query shows me the correct content and the correct id
but it's showing the id number 15 before the id number 17 even if I set 'order' to 'id DESC'

the result should be:
first record : id 17 and the 
second record : id 15

is there a way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming you database is MySQL: You can either write a more complex query (which will NOT translate into a `find` very well) but will be optimized for performance. Or (IMO) use a simpler technique (until performance is an issue),  run two `find`'s sequentially - the first returns the maximum created date, the second uses the maximum created date to find the correct Message record.

Comment: What do you mean by the first part of your reply AgRizzo

Comment: You cannot [**order before grouping**](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+order+before+group), so you'll need a [**subquery**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries), which is what @AgRizzo is referring to as the more complex solution.

Comment: Your `order` clause in the subquery is irrelevant. You need to add the `order` clause  to `$conversationInProgress = $this->Message->find('all'...`